# Cronómetro deja de contar cuando le doy término la aplicación SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode

El cronómetro funciona perfectamente mientras navego por otras views y cuando salgo de la aplicación, pero si le doy termino a la aplicación se detiene. Necesito que funcione igual al cronómetro que tiene el Iphone, que cuando termine la aplicación o apague el teléfono el cronómetro siga funcionando hasta llegar a los 3 minutos y se detenga...

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento

```
class CuentaViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = Timer()
    var timeCounter = 0
    var backgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
    //var backgroundTask = BackgroundTask()

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier!)
        })

        //backgroundTask.startBackgroundTask()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let currentRunLoop = RunLoop.current
            let timeInterval = 1.0
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            self.timer.tolerance = timeInterval * 0.1
            currentRunLoop.add(self.timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
            currentRunLoop.run()
        }
    }

@objc func updateTimer () {
    timeCounter += 1
    let minutes = Int(timeCounter) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(timeCounter) % 60

    print("timeCounter", timeCounter)
    lbl.text = String(timeCounter)
    let count = timeCounter
    if (count == 120){
            self.timer.invalidate()
    }

    //timeLabel.fadeTransition(0.4)
    //timeLabel.text = String(format: "%02i:%02i",minutes,seconds)
}



    @IBAction func btnlogout(_ sender: Any) {
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
    }

}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme,
desde ya,
muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El cronometro deja de existir si el app es terminada, no hay nada que puedas hacer con eso, no se que quieres hacer con esta info, lo que pudieras hacer es hacer una Local notification para avisarle al usuario que se terminó el cronometro que estaba corriendo y al abrir el app seguir con tu flujo.

Espero que te sirva.